# Grouping rows in mysql in clausule group by

Tags: mysql

I need to do the next :

```
ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC  
-------|-------|------- 
      1|abc    |5 
      1|def    |4 
      1|ghi    |9 
      2|jkl    |8 
      2|mno    |3
```

then, i need make a GRUOP BY by columnA, SUM(columnB)

and i need in the column concat abc, def, ghi in one row for the 1 and for the 2 jkl, mno.

How can i do it?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggreagation functions an group by eg:

```
select ColumnA, group_concat(ColumnB), sum(ColumnC)
from my_table
group by ColumnA
```

Comment: I don have sufficient reputation. I had give this one.